# Why are controls in the wrong place if they're positioned while the form is scrolled?

Tags: delphi, scrollbar

Consider this form, with a label 'Observer here' and a button 'Click':

[image: a label near the left edge of the form, with a button]

On button click I am setting the label's `Left` to 10 (`Label1.Left :=10;`)

I am getting correctly as in the second image:

[image: form with label near left edge]

Then, I scroll the form to the right:

[image: same form as before, but scrolled right so label is hidden]

Now, after clicking the button I get a problem, which is shown in 4th image:

[image: same form, scrolled left, but label visible near middle instead of left]

The label's `Left` is not 10 anymore. It's more than 10, but I need it to be 10. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

Label1.Left := 10 ; Means 10 left from the **current** border(form1.left).

so Label1.Left := 10 ; will not produce the same result always ,It depends on `Form1.HorzScrollBar.Position ;`

You have to code like

```
Label1.Left := 10 - Form1.HorzScrollBar.Position  ;
```

You can see this pattern on design time by select a component in your form1 and adjust the scroll bar ,you can notice that in the object Inspector  left value of the selected component will also change when moving the scrollbar

**You can understand it like this**

If you have HorzScrollBar then if you add components and set their left value very high, the form1 will not increase its width but its virtual width handled by scrollbar will get increased, all the coordination values will give the value relative to form1 not related to the virtual space

Comment: refer http://books.google.lk/books?id=V9t0lA-BPUAC&pg=PA349&lpg=PA349&dq=HorzScrollBar.Position+and+left+in+delphi&source=bl&ots=4-VEnO6j9k&sig=mmaYp0uooE-QveNIjUhk5eZoyyU&hl=en&ei=nBegTpT8D4f3rQebkv2JAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Can anyone tell me whether the same pattern is used in visual studio winforms.

Comment: @rakesh if you think this is the answer you wanted you can accept this as a solution or you can give some feedback

Comment: +1 This does indeed appear to be the correct answer. This I never knew until today!